# Keep extending older boxes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I check if previous boxes are still valid and extend them to the right?
As of now, if the condition is meet, the old box stops and the new one starts drawing. But I also want to keep drawing the old box if the condition for that is still valid.
[image]

```
var float first_low = na
var float first_high = na
var bool can_draw_bull = false
var bool can_draw_bear = false
var box _fubox = na
var box _bearFUBox = na

if (bullFu)     // Bullish FU found
    first_low := low  // Low of FU wick
    can_draw_bull := true    // We are allowed to draw a line
    _fubox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=open, right=bar_index, bottom=low, bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 80), border_color = color.new(color.green, 100))
else
    if (can_draw_bull)
        if (close < first_low)  // Low is broken with body
            can_draw_bull := false   // Stop drawing
        else
            box.set_right(_fubox, bar_index+1)

if (bearFu)     // Bearish FU found
    first_high := high  // High of FU wick
    can_draw_bear := true    // We are allowed to draw a line
    _bearFUBox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=high, right=bar_index, bottom=open, bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 80), border_color = color.new(color.red, 100))
else
    if (can_draw_bear)
        if (close > first_high)  // High is broken with body
            can_draw_bear := false   // Stop drawing
        else
            //line.set_x2(l, bar_index+1)   // Update x2 position of the line (move it to the right)
            box.set_right(_bearFUBox, bar_index+1)
```

Comment: Did you write this code?